# How to ensure that localData in JavaScript is a number, not a string, without having to constantly make it a number?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So I have the following code:

```
function save(variableL,variable) {
  localStorage.setItem(variableL,Number(variable));
}
let points = localStorage.getItem('pointsL');
  if (points === null) {
    points = 0;
    save('pointsL',points);
}
let line_segments = localStorage.getItem('line_segmentsL');
if (line_segments === null) {
  line_segments = 0;
  save('line_segmentsL',line_segments);
}
let points_per_sec = 0;
let line_segment_price = 10;

function pointClick() {
  points = Number(points);
  points += 1;
}
function lineSegmentPurchase() {
  points = Number(points);
  line_segments = Number(line_segments);
  if (Number(points) >= line_segment_price) {
    points -= line_segment_price;
    line_segments += 1;
  }
}
function frame() {
  points = Number(points);
  line_segments = Number(line_segments);
  points += points_per_sec / 20;
}
let frame_interval = setInterval(frame, 50);

function saving() {
  save('pointsL',points);
  save('line_segmentsL',line_segments);
}
let saving_interval = setInterval(saving, 1000);
```

And I constantly have errors and mistakes. (this is just the most recent, I've been changing it over and over with no avail). Sometimes it reloads and my points are just completely blank, and always when I click my button to buy a line segment, it takes four to five clicks to register, and then it sometimes makes the price go to Infinity or NaN.
As you can see, I've got my code absolutely littered with Number() functions and I feel like it isn't helping and I'm not sure why these glitches keep occurring. I'm certain there's just some method I'm overlooking, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. As documentation of [Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) return value state:

> A DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

Comment: ah, ok. do you know why my button needs to be clicked several times to react? The code is just `<button id = 'lineSegmentPurchaseID' class = 'product' onclick = 'lineSegmentPurchase()'></button>` so I don't know why it wouldn't react each time.

Comment: For that would be useful if you create an stackblitz or alike. Your code uses variables with different scopes, is difficult to follow what happens there. Take some time to refactor it and then it will be clear where the problem is.